# Composite of Galois extensions is Galois, a particular proof.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

This has been asked over and over again on math.stackexchange and I will ask it again.

> Let $L_1/K$ and $L_2/K$ be finite Galois extensions of $K$ inside a common field, then $L_1L_2/K$ is a finite Galois extension.

I'm interested in one common proof of that fact. It goes like this:

> $L_1L_2/K$ is finite so it suffices to prove that $L_1L_2$ is the splitting field of a separable polynomial over $K$. $L_i$ is the splitting field of a separable polynomial $f_i$ over $K$. Then $L_1L_2$ is the splitting field for the product of $f_1$ and $f_2$ with common factors only used once.

However, to me it seems that this only works when (the product of) common factors belong to $K[X]$ and I cannot think of a reason why this would be guaranteed (except e.g. when $L_1\cap L_2 = K$).What am I missing, or is this a bogus proof?

Comment: Why does it only work when the product of common factors belongs in $K[x]$? Note that the "product of $f_1$ and $f_2$ with common factors used only once" is the polynomial $\frac{f_1f_2}{\gcd(f_1 , f_2)}$, which is indeed a separable polynomial in $K[x]$. Proving that $L_1L_2$ is the splitting field is quite clear from the roots of this polynomial. Besides , the product of common factors is the $\gcd$, which is being taken and therefore belongs in $K[x]$ anyway.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Why is $\frac{f_1f_2}{gcd(f_1, f_2)}$ in $K[x]$ for any field $K$? I don't understand the scentence "the product of common factors is the gcd, which is being taken and therefore belongs in [] anyway"?

Comment: @user428487 Let us take an example : Let $L_1$ be the splitting field of $(x^2+1)(x^2+2)$ over $\mathbb Q$, and $L_2$ be the splitting field of $(x^2+1)(x^2+3)$ over $\mathbb Q$. "Common factors" of the two polynomials are many : there is $(x-i)$ , $(x+i)$ and $x^2+1$, because each of these polynomials divide both the polynomials above. But the *greatest* of these i.e. $x^2+1$ also has rational coefficients, while the others do not. The product of all the common degree-one factors of the two polynomials i.e. $(x-i)$ and $(x+i)$ leads to $x^2+1$ (that is : product of common factors is the GCD)

Comment: @user428487 Continuing, the gcd belongs in $K[x]$ because as Arthur says below, it can be computed using the Euclidean algorithm, which at each step ensures that both remainder and quotient polynomial remain in $K[x]$, hence at the final step of the algorithm, the GCD comes out which will also be in $K[x]$. Finally, $\frac{f_1f_2}{\gcd(f_1,f_2)}$ is just $(x^2+1)(x^2+2)(x^2+3)$ i.e. the $x^2+1$ appears only once in the product. This will belong in $K[x]$ because $f_1$ is a multiple of $\gcd(f_1,f_2)$ in $K[x]$ so $\frac{f_1f_2}{\gcd(f_1,f_2)}$ is a product of two $K[x]$-polynomials.

Comment: @user428487 Finally, *because we removed that common root by dividing by the gcd*, the polynomial $\frac{f_1f_2}{\gcd(f_1,f_2)}$ has *no* repeated roots, and is hence separable. There is a chance you may still be confused : please ask, however if you are satisfied kindly drop a comment in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

Consider, for instance, $L_1 = \Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ and $L_2 = \Bbb Q(\sqrt3)$ over $K = \Bbb Q$. Then $L_1$ is the splitting field of $f_1(x) = x^2-2$ and $L_2$ is the splitting field of $f_2(x) = x^2-3$. The field $L_1L_2$ is the splitting field of $f_1f_2$ over $K$. Nothing about this construction gives you a polynomial outside of $K[x]$, and it may be applied quite generally, even when $f_1$ and $f_2$ have factors in common.

If it turns out that $f_1$ and $f_2$ have roots in common, then they have a non-1 $\gcd$. But that $\gcd$ is still an element of $K[x]$, as for instance the Euclidean algorithm applies, and doesn't take you out of $K[x]$.

So "the product of $f_1$ and $f_2$ with common factors only used once" is given by
$$
\frac{f_1f_2}{\gcd(f_1, f_2)}\in K[x]
$$

Comment: There’s no reason to demand that there be no repeated factors in your polynomial, after all.

Comment: @Lubin If you want to show that an extension is Galois, you need a separable polynomial. Which is to say no repeated factors.

Comment: If you want to show that it’s *normal*, all you need is a polynomial. In characteristic zero, all extensions are separable. Thus in this case, it’s enough to find a polynomial.

Comment: @Lubin That's applying theory, not the definition. Also, I'm not writing a proof. I'm explaining the given one, and they did it and therefore so do I.

Answer (score 2):

We can prove it's separable and normal independently.

As $L_1/K$ is Galois, $L_1$ is the splitting field of a separable polynomial $f(x)\in K[x] \subseteq L_2[x]$, the roots of $f(x)$ generate $L_1$ over $K$, so it generate $L_1L_2$ over $L_2$. In other words, $L_1L_2$ is the splitting field of a separable polynomial $f(x)$ over $L_2$, so $L_1L_2/L_2$ is Galois, hence separable.

Since $L_2/K$ is separable and separable is transitive, we know that $L_1L_2/K$ is separable.

Then we prove it's normal by your argument, no need to worry whether it contains multiple factors.

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma:**

Let $L_1$ be the splitting field of $f_1(x)$ over $K$.

Let $L_2$ be the splitting field of $f_2(x)$ over $K$.

Then I claim that $L_1 L_2$ (the compositum of the two fields, as subfields of the algebraic closure of $K$) is the splitting field of $f_1(x) f_2(x)$.

*proof* Since $L_1 L_2$ contains $L_1$ it is clear that $f_1(x)$ splits in this field. Same with $f_2(x)$. So the polynomial $f_1(x) f_2(x)$ will also split completely in $L_1 L_2$.

---

This implies that $L_1 L_2 / K$ is a normal extension.

The polynomial $f_1(x) f_2(x)$ may have multiple roots if $f_1$ and $f_2$ share some roots. In that case the polynomial would not be seperable. But as discussed in comments that can be factored out and $L_1 L_2$ is the splitting field of that factored out polynomial, which is seperable. So it is a Galois extension. But note that if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are irreducible polynomials then they cannot share any common factors, so in that case $f_1(x) f_2(x)$ would be seperable.

Note that only one of the two fields needs to be Galois for the compositum to be Galois, but proving this would take a bit more.